# Aspose words API - mail merge functionality - can the "merged" text be richtext (with styles/images/bullets/tables)?

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

Looking for word api which can perform mail merge type of functionality with richtext. Basically, text will be richtext/formatted text with fonts styles and WILL have

```
a) images
b) bullets
c) tables
```

Overall purpose: Create a word template with bookmarks. Get get data from DB(for those fields) and insert. Data will be html text/richtext.  Autogenerate word document. python or .net api will be preferred.

```
Can Aspose.words work with richtext as described above?  Any other recommendations for excellent word APIs?
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this using Aspose.Words. You can use IFieldMergingCallback to insert formatted text upon mail merge. For example, see the following link
https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.mailmerging/ifieldmergingcallback
In case of reach text (if you mean RTF or MarkDown formats) you first need to read this content into a separate instance of Document and then use DocumentBuilder.InsertDocument method
https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/documentbuilder/methods/insertdocument

The following code example shows how to use InsertHtml method in IFieldMergingCallback

```cs
[Test]
public void Test001()
{
    Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\in.docx");
    doc.MailMerge.FieldMergingCallback = new HandleMergeFieldInsertHtml();
    const string html = @"<h1>Hello world!</h1>";
    doc.MailMerge.Execute(new string[] { "myField" }, new object[] { html });
    doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
}

private class HandleMergeFieldInsertHtml : IFieldMergingCallback
{
    void IFieldMergingCallback.FieldMerging(FieldMergingArgs args)
    {
        FieldMergeField field = args.Field;

        // Insert the text for this merge field as HTML data, using DocumentBuilder
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(args.Document);
        builder.MoveToMergeField(args.DocumentFieldName);
        builder.Write(field.TextBefore ?? "");
        builder.InsertHtml((string)args.FieldValue);

        // The HTML text itself should not be inserted
        // We have already inserted it as an HTML
        args.Text = "";
    }

    void IFieldMergingCallback.ImageFieldMerging(ImageFieldMergingArgs args)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

If you would like manually format the text, then you can use DocumentBuilder appropriate properties.

```cs
[Test]
public void Test001()
{
    Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Temp\in.docx");
    doc.MailMerge.FieldMergingCallback = new HandleMergeFieldInsertText();
    const string text = @"Hello world!";
    doc.MailMerge.Execute(new string[] { "myField" }, new object[] { text });
    doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
}

private class HandleMergeFieldInsertText : IFieldMergingCallback
{
    void IFieldMergingCallback.FieldMerging(FieldMergingArgs args)
    {
        FieldMergeField field = args.Field;

        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(args.Document);
        builder.MoveToMergeField(args.DocumentFieldName);
        // Apply style or other formatting.
        builder.ParagraphFormat.StyleIdentifier = StyleIdentifier.Heading1;
        builder.Write(field.TextBefore ?? "");
        builder.Write((string)args.FieldValue);

        // The  text itself should not be inserted
        // We have already inserted it using DocumentBuilder.
        args.Text = "";
    }

    void IFieldMergingCallback.ImageFieldMerging(ImageFieldMergingArgs args)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.

Comment: What is difference between first and second method? Second one is not mail merge.
To be precise, we have a word docx with tables. Tables have questions. We need to export responses to same word docx template. Each Table cell/response will have formatted text - styles, fonts, colors, bullets, and images. 
Can we create a document for each cell and then insert it into particular cell using mail-merge or replacement functionality using first method? Are there any restrictions?

Comment: FieldMergingCallback : HTML insert - Can this HTML have tables and bullets and will it still work?

Comment: 1. Mail Merge in Aspose.Words mimics the corresponding MS Word functionality. This makes impossible to extend the template syntax, so LINQ Reporting Engine was introduced, which uses its own template syntax.
https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Introduction+to+LINQ+Reporting+Engine

2. Sure, you can create a document and then insert it where it is required in the template. 

3. Yes, HTML can contain tables, images, bullets etc. After insertion all content will be preserved as well as its formatting.

Comment: Are css styles supported? Meaning if we want to format HTML text with particular font name/font style OR use MS styles of the inserted template.

Comment: Yes, css styles are supported. Also, InsetHtml has a flag that indicates whether to inherit DocumentBuilder's formatting. https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.documentbuilder/inserthtml/methods/1

Comment: Alexey - We are able to do simple mail merge but unable to apply styles. Do you have any test working example?
Secondly, can we apply "MS Word Styles" 
Example: Apply  "Heading 1" Style to text.

Comment: @nitinkhosla I added two code examples in the answer. One for inserting HTML and other for inserting text and applying formatting using DocumentBuilder. hope this helps.

Comment: Can we do same with aspose.slides and aspose.cells for excel and ppt files?

Comment: @nitinkhosla As far as know there is no mail merge functionality in Aspose.Cells and Aspose.Slides. But you still can fill excel and presentation files with formatted data using Aspose.Cells  https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/data/ and Aspose.Slides.https://docs.aspose.com/slides/net/adding-formatting-and-manipulating-text/